# How to write two operations at a time inside function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two tables in my database, i want to get both datas with one function using nodejs

My table name is ContactGroup and Group

My code:

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
    ContactGroup.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('group.id')),
            'contactCount'
        ]],
        include: [{
            model: Group,
        }],
    }).then(seenData => {
        console.log('seenData:', seenData);
    });


    Group.findAll().then(function (data) {
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```

Like above code, i am writing ContactGroup.findandcount and Group.findall, i checked this api via postman, but only one working here,
I want both of them working? help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you take a global array or object and use it in follwing manner

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
    var globalObj={};
        ContactGroup.findAndCountAll({
            attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('group.id')),
                'contactCount'
            ]],
            include: [{
                model: Group,
            }],
        }).then(seenData => { globalObj.seendata=seenData;return Group.findAll();})


        .then(function (data) {
    globalObj.alldata=data;
            return res.status(200).send(globalObj);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err.message);
        });
    };
```

Comment: try it now and let me know you specific requirement

Comment: I want to send seenData datas into controllers with angularjs
for example i want to use like that $scope.somestuff = response.data;( i want to get "seenData" values into $scope.somestuff)

Comment: where do you want to see all data from  Group.findAll().?

Comment: you can get both table in your response and you have to use
`$scope.somestuff = response.data.seendata;` in angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159196/discussion-between-hemant-rajpoot-and-ganesh-pandiyan).

Comment: it showing as undefined,i am getting seendata response in console of my terminal, but not in my angular?

Comment: i gusse you need to change you question sorry but i can not help with angular i can help you send data from server but how you handle it on client side i cant help you with but try $scope.somestuff=JSON.parse(response.data).seendata;

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and try :

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
ContactGroup.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('group.id')),
        'contactCount'
    ]],
    include: [{
        model: Group,
    }],
}).then(seenData => {
    console.log('seenData:', seenData);
    Group.findAll().then(function (data) {
       return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
       return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
 });    
};
```

Comment: I am getting ContactGroup datas in console, but i am getting Group datas in api checked via postman, I need both table datas to be execute in postman as json

Answer (score 0):

although others  answers are  correct but as i saw there are two **independent  async function** so it's better to populate them parallel (more performance gain) as below.

```
exports.getNewGroup = function (req, res) {
    p1= ContactGroup.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('group.id')),
            'contactCount'
        ]],
        include: [{
            model: Group,
        }],
    })
    p2 =Group.findAll() 

    Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(values => { 
        console.log(values);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
       return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });


};
```